# How to make just the name typed into the input box displayed in italics. Please look at this code

Tags: javascript, html, plaintext, string-literals, italics

So I only want the name which appears twice in the response to show up italicized.I am a real noob so please help me out and be clear. I appreciate it 
http://dave-reed.com/book3e/Ch5/greet.html
Here is the example website. I want your name only out of the response to be italicized.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0042)http://dave-reed.com/book3e/Ch5/greet.html -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   <title> Greetings </title>
 </head>

 <body>
   <h2>Greetings</h2>
   <p>
     Enter your name: <input type="text" id="nameBox" size="12" value="">
   </p>
   <input type="button" value="Click for Greeting" onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML=
                     'Hello ' + document.getElementById('nameBox').value + 
                     ', welcome to my page.<br>Do you mind if I call you ' +
                     document.getElementById('nameBox').value + '?';"> 
   <hr>
   <div id="outputDiv"></div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Welome to Stack Overflow.  Your question is getting downvoted because it doesn't quite meet the criteria at http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic .  One thing missing from your question is any explanation of what you have tried to achieve the result.   A simple google of 'HTML italic' will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0042)http://dave-reed.com/book3e/Ch5/greet.html -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   <title> Greetings </title>
<style type="text/css">
.italic {
    font-style:italic;
}
</style>
 </head>

 <body>   
<h2>Greetings</h2>
   <p>
     Enter your name: <input type="text" id="nameBox" size="12" value="">
   </p>
   <input type="button" value="Click for Greeting" onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML=
                     'Hello <span class=\'italic\'>' + document.getElementById('nameBox').value + 
                     '</span>, welcome to my page.<br>Do you mind if I call you <span class=\'italic\'>' +
                     document.getElementById('nameBox').value + '</span>?';"> 
   <hr>
   <div id="outputDiv"></div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new CSS rule:

```
.test{
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Then add `<span class=\'test\'> </span>` around each instance of the name, like this...

```
 <body>
   <h2>Greetings</h2>
   <p>
     Enter your name: <input type="text" id="nameBox" size="12" value="">
   </p>
   <input type="button" value="Click for Greeting" onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML=
                     'Hello <span class=\'test\'>' + document.getElementById('nameBox').value + 
                     '</span>, welcome to my page.<br>Do you mind if I call you <span class=\'test\'>' +
                     document.getElementById('nameBox').value + '</span>?';"> 
   <hr>
   <div id="outputDiv"></div>

</body>
```

View fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7kVTA/1/)

Comment: The class doesn't need to be named `test` - you can call it anything you'd like (following CSS naming guidelines) so long as you make sure to change the class name in the `span` tags.